# Is there a way to attach a .pdf file as an attachment and simultaneously insert a .html file as an image in the body of the email using ms access

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, pdf, while-loop

I have written some VBA code in MS Access where I am attempting to do the following:

Action:
Attach a pdf file as an attachment to a MS Outlook email
Insert an html file, that's saved as a .html file on a different file path, into the HTMLBody of the same MS Outlook email; and
Loop through a record set

Situation:
Currently, I have written code that attaches the 1st pdf, as an attachment, and inserts the 1st html file, as an image, into the HTML body. However, when the code loops back through the 2nd, 3rd, etc it:
Attaches the 2nd pdf as an attachment (as it should), and inserts the 1st html and 2nd html image, into the body; loops through again and
Attaches the 3rd pdf as an attachment(as it should), and inserts the 1st html, 2nd html and 3rd html image, into the body; and so on

Desired Results:
I would like for the code to loop through and attach the:
1st pdf file as an attachment, and the 1st  html file as an image in the HTMLbody
2nd pdf file as an attachment, and the 2nd  html file as an image in the HTMLbody; and
Continue through the end of the data set where the email contains 1 pdf file as an attachment; and 1 html image in the HTML body of the Outlook email.

```
Private Sub cmdEmailLetters_Click()


    Dim folderName As String
    Dim FSOLibrary As Object
    Dim FSOFolder As Object
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    Dim FilePathName As String
    Dim FilePathName2 As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsEmail As Recordset
    Dim rsEmail2 As Recordset
    Dim rsFileName As Recordset
    Dim rsGID As Recordset
    Dim rsFNHtml As Object
    Dim rsFName As Object
    Dim strline, strHTML
    Dim count As Integer



    'Set the file name to a variable
    folderName = "H:\Customer Outreach\Customer_Letters\"


    'Set all the references to the FSO Library
    Set FSOLibrary = New FileSystemObject
    Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)
    Set FSOFile = FSOFolder.Files
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList") 
    Set rsEmail = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList") 
    Set rsEmail2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList") 
    Set rsFileName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList") 
    Set rsGID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList") 
    Set rsFNHtml = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList")
    Set rsFName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestFinalEmailList")



    'Use For Each loop to loop through each file in the folder
    For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

        Open "H:\Customer Outreach\Customer_Letters_html\Customer Request - " & rsFNHtml!FILE_NAME_Html 
        & ".html" For Input As 1
          If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
           Do While Not EOF(1)
           Input #1, strline
           strHTML = strHTML & strline
         Loop
           Close #1
           rsFNHtml.MoveNext
        End If

        If rsGID!CustID = rsFileName!FILE_NAME Then
        Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MailOutlook = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

              With MailOutlook

                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                .To = rsEmail!CUST_Mn_EMAIL
                .CC = rsEmail2!SCND_EMAIL
                ''.bcc = ""
                .Subject = "TEST"
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance
                .HTMLBody = strHTML
                .Attachments.Add (FSOFile)
                '.Send
                .Display    'Used during testing without sending (Comment out .Send if using this line)
            End With
               Else
            MsgBox rsGID!GRANTEEID & " No file matching " & strPath & strFilter & " found." & vbCrLf & _
                "Processing terminated."
             Exit Sub
         End If

        rsGID.MoveNext
        rsFileName.MoveNext
        rsEmail.MoveNext
        rsEmail2.MoveNext

        Next

        'Release the memory
        Set FSOLibrary = Nothing
        Set FSOFolder = Nothing
        Set FSOFile = Nothing
        Set rsEmail = Nothing
        Set rsFNHtml = Nothing
        Set strHTML = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing


MsgBox "Email transfer is complete!", , "STATUS"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am confused. You say code should and does attach 3 PDF files and insert 3 images and then say you want only 1 PDF file attached and only 1 image inserted.

Comment: From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the tour to get an overview of how this site works. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. Also familiarize yourself with the help center, especially [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In the immediate beginning of your `For Each FSOFile` loop, you load the `HTML` part (including the image) into the variable `strHTML`, which you then assign to `.HTMLBody`. But you never clear this variable in preparation for the next email. Add `strHTML = ""` before the `Do loop:

```
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    strHTML = ""                'add this line
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Input #1, strline
        strHTML = strHTML & strline
    Loop
    Close #1
    rsFNHtml.MoveNext
End If
```

Note also, `(rs.EOF And rs.BOF)` should be `(rs.EOF Or rs.BOF)`